Probability of picking company that outperforms
I saw a comment about how unlikely it is to pick stocks that outperform the market, as very few of them account for a large portion of the gains.
Someone said it would be like having 500 marbles — 497 black, 3 white — and picking 50. So, what is the probability of picking all 3 white marbles, given that you choose 50 marbles without replacement?
My thought is:
There are $ \binom{50}{3} $ ways of choosing the 3 white marbles.
Then, there are $ \binom{497}{47} $ ways of choosing the remaining 47 black marbles from the 497 black ones, as they are unique.
Thus, the probability should be:
$P = \frac{{\binom{50}{3} \times \binom{497}{47}}}{{\binom{500}{50}}}$
However, the probability seems insanely low, which makes me doubt it because, at first glance, I’d expect it to be something like:
$\frac{3}{500} \times \text{some combination of } 50 \text{ marbles from 500}$
Apologies for formatting, I’m on mobile.

Not sure I get the factor of $\binom {50}3$....there are $\binom {497}{47}$ ways to choose $50$ out of $500$ given that the $50$ must include the special $3$.

Yes you can arrange the 3 marbles in 50C3 ways

That doesn't make sense.  The binomial symbols count the unordered collections.  Thus your denominator correctly counts all the subsets of size $50$ from the full $500$ and the numerator should just be $\binom {497}{47}$...which counts the subsets of size $50$ that contain all three white ones (as those subsets are defined by selecting $47$ black balls.  So, the value you thought was too low was actually a huge over estimate.

To do the monster math version:  each white ball has a one tenth chance of being chosen so the answer should be about $\frac 1{10^3}=.001$.  That's actually a bit of an over estimate, as knowing that the first white one was chosen slightly lowers the chance for the others.  Indeed the true value is a bit lower, namely $0.000946471$.

On the one hand, in a combinatorics-oriented probability problem, I normally favor using combinatorics to compute the probability.  On the other hand, for a somewhat inexperienced problem solver, whose intuition has not yet been expanded by confronting 50+ of such problems, I advocate going back to basics.
So, I will present a primitive approach that does not rely on expanded intuition.

Label the marbles $~W_1, ~W_2, ~W_3, ~B_1, ~B_2, ~\cdots, ~B_{497}.~$
The first question is, what is the probability that your selection includes all $~3~$ white marbles, specifically because the first $~3~$ marbles that you selected are all white?
The probability of this occurring is
$$A = \frac{3}{500} \times \frac{2}{499} \times \frac{1}{498}. \tag1 $$
The next question is, how should this computation be affected by the fact that you are selecting $~50~$ marbles (without replacement), and the $~3~$ selected marbles can each occur in any of the $~50~$ positions?
For example, given the computation in (1) above, the probability that the white marbles chosen are the 10-th, 20-th, and 30-th is also equal to $~A.~$
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{50}{3}~$ ways of selecting the positions that the white marbles will occupy.
So, the final answer should be
$$\binom{50}{3} \times \frac{3!}{500 \times 499 \times 498} = \binom{50}{3} \times \frac{3!}{\frac{500!}{497!}} = \frac{\binom{50}{3}}{\binom{500}{3}}. \tag2 $$

Now, the question becomes, how can you expand your intuition so that the computation in (2) above makes sense?
Consider the following alternative way of selecting marbles.
You are going to arbitrarily place the $~500~$ marbles in a row, with the $~3~$ white marbles randomly placed among the $~500~$ positions.
You are then going to select the first $~50~$ marbles in the  row.  What is the probability that all $~3~$ white marbles are included in the first $~50~$ marbles selected?
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{500}{3}~$ possible distributions of the $~3~$ white marbles among the $~500~$ positions, of which $~\displaystyle \binom{50}{3}~$ of these distributions are favorable.
Therefore, the computation of
$$\frac{\binom{50}{3}}{\binom{500}{3}}$$
makes sense.

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
A somewhat advanced approach, that is similar to the approach attempted by the original poster, is as follows:
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{3}~$ ways of selecting which $~3~$ white marbles will be selected.
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{497}{47}~$ ways of selecting which $~47~$ black marbles will be selected.
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{500}{50}~$ ways of selecting which $~50~$ marbles will be selected.
Therefore, the probability should be
$$\frac{\binom{3}{3} ~\binom{497}{47}}{\binom{500}{50}},$$
which is equivalent to the previous computation.
